# Metro MahApps MessageBox theme

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

Maybe someone could show me how to correctly implement Async message into Metro window that it would have application's current theme and accent?

The code taken from the demo sample works, but theme and accent remain default:

```
private async void ClosingApp(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = !_shutdown;
        if (_shutdown) return;
        var mySettings = new MetroDialogSettings()
        {
            AffirmativeButtonText = "Quit",
            NegativeButtonText = "Cancel",
            AnimateShow = true,
            AnimateHide = false
        };
        var result = await this.ShowMessageAsync("Quit application?",
            "Sure you want to quit application?",
            MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative, mySettings);

        _shutdown = result == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative;
        if (_shutdown)
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

When I simply change the theme:

```
 private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // set the Red accent and dark theme only to the current window
        var theme = ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseDark");
        var accent = ThemeManager.GetAccent("Red");
        ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, accent, theme);
    }
```

I get the default white and blue MessageBox. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code and it is working. I've only transformed the MenuItem_Click in a Button_Click but it is irrelevant.

I'm getting the black background and a red Quit like below, **iff** I close the App after clicking the settings button.

[image]

instead of the initial

[image]

I have the standard Window1.xaml starting with

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="TestFrontend.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Closing="App_Closing"
    Title="Test" Height="600" Width="600"
    >
```

and the Resources in the App.xaml

```
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: It seems like without the default (Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml, Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml) Sources in the App.xaml the MessageBox with theme does not work. I just needed to add those. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have to add the above shown Resources in the App.xaml. I'm glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add the default Resource Dictionaries

`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />`
in the App.xaml